# I made changes but want to undo them. When i checkout a previous revision, git won't let me commit or push it. Says there's no changes

Tags: git, github

I made some changes and pushed them to remote master. I now want to go back to a previous version. I tried doing:

```
git reset --hard a3b40f2d1c764
```

But after doing that, while it moved the local HEAD, it won't let me push that to remote master. How do I make that the current remote master?

Answer (score 1):

You have to force-push by doing this:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

Comment: @Aerovistae what's the difference?

Comment: `force` pushes No Matter What....whatever's on origin is getting overwritten. `force-with-lease` basically checks to see if anyone else has pushed work to it since the last time you did, and stops the push if so. So you don't need it if you're working alone, unless you're afraid of ghosts.

Answer (score 1):

You can force it:

```
git push -f origin master
```

However I would suggest using [revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) here

Comment: This seemed to work: `git push --force origin master`  Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing wrong, revert is just a good habit of not breaking things when you are not working alone (reset will diverge your repository from anyone else using it).

Comment: Also this is the reason why git is not letting you push without **force**.